# What is the scope of gambling prohibitions for JW's?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, gambling

I know that gambling is forbidden for a Jehovah's Witness. Would this include a phone in competition on the radio, for example to win money or a holiday?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your question, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Answer (score 3):

I am one of Jehovah's Witnesses.

We don't gamble because:

1. We avoid greediness.
2. We don't want to put our faith in the "god of Good Luck" (Isaiah 65:11).
3. We don't want to take someone else's money in exchange for nothing.

**This does *not* include a radio contest because the other radio listeners in the contest aren't losing any money if they don't win the prize.**

With regard to your follow up question, "*would a football team of Jehovah's Witnesses be able to participate in the coin toss to decide which end they started from?*" - Yes they would as long as they weren't doing something similar to what is mentioned in this paragraph taken from a 2011 Watchtower: "*For example, auspicious numbers are chosen for lottery tickets; the uttering of certain words is forbidden among superstitious mah-jongg players; and a puff of air is blown over dice before they are thrown. Why? Gamblers often believe that luck will, or at least might, influence the outcome.*" (http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2011167)

Here is an article that gives more details on how far to take the prohibition:
http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2002808